# New Vuex store properties are not reactive

Tags: vue.js, vuex, reactive, quasar

I use Vue.js and more specifically Quasar, with a Vuex store.

The properties which initially existed at the initialization of the store are reactive, but not any of the new properties I created afterwards on an object of the store, even though I created them with `Vue.set()` as required by the framework.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

48h of debug and I found that I wrote `import Vue form 'Vue'` instead of `import Vue from 'vue'` in the mutation file.